# OpenACC in Visual C++

Tags: cuda, opencl, openmp, openacc

I want to parallelize my codes with OpenACC directives. It's said that it is a crossplatform API. The developer firms are giving no information about OpenACC in VisualStudio. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, but VS does not support (the much easier to implement) OpenMP past the 10-years old 2.0 version and you want OpenACC support?!

Comment: Why not give libraries a try?  They are just as easy to use as directives and have support for Visual Studio.  Any of the NVIDIA libraries, the CULA libraries, or ArrayFire (the one I work on) will be good for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there are only OpenACC implementations available from PGI, CAPS, and Cray. I think PGI mentioned a beta-level plug-in for Visual Studio in a [2010 newsletter](http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v2n3a3.htm) but I don't think they have any official support. CAPS only mentions Linux support on their website. Cray is only available to users of Cray clusters, and I don't believe they run Windows.

So I think currently you need a Linux machine or possibly a Mac. I would expect this to change in the future but I'm not aware of specific plans.

Comment: "Cray is only available to users of Cray clusters, and I don't believe they run Windows." They did, actually. The CX1 deskside supercomputer was sold with Windows 2008 HPC Server but now the product line is discontinued.

Comment: @HristoIliev yes, but the compiler was VS

Comment: Update: PGI now part of NVIDIA, visit https://developer.nvidia.com/openacc-toolkit -- Here you find plenty of information regarding VS & OpenACC

Answer (score 4):

CAPS Entreprise has now also a Windows version available: http://www.caps-entreprise.com/products/caps-compilers/